# Isn't MagicalRecord supposed to automatically migrate new attributes?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.6, core-data-migration, magicalrecord

I have a CoreData store, managed using MagicalRecord.  I added some new Attributes to an existing Entity.  This is the code I used to setup the stack:

```
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"foo.sqlite"];
```

When I ran the app (using the Debugger), the old store was deleted and replaced with the changed xcdatamodeld definition.  It was my understanding that MagicalRecord would handle the migration automatically... am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have a xcmappingmodel defined.